# Aggregating distributed logfiles into one logfile on real-time

Tags: monitoring, distributed, logfile

I got in legacy a system which save its logfiles on 15 different servers during 1 job run.

Now, there is a need to aggregate all of them into 1 file, and just as important- on real-time.

I started by ssh through python, but its not answering the real-time need.

Any general direction you recommend on?! Any opensource code that could help me here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple tool, which I’m using, is [fluentd](http://www.fluentd.org/) you can set up small services which run `tail -f` on those different log-files on the nodes directly and send it to the one central server. There you can store it into a file or database, or what ever else you whish.

There are also other similar solutions, like [logstash](http://logstash.net/) for instance, however I’m used to fluentd

Answer (score 0):

It depends mostly of how you are logging, which tools, which OS...

There is the tools suggested by peter which work very well. If your legacy systems are  already using syslog, you can implement too syslog or [rsyslog forwarding](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsyslog_reliable_forwarding.html).